# Parse list of strings to Int

Tags: haskell

I'm reading positions from a file and getting this:

```
["[6,5,3]","[4,1,4]","[3,7,6]"]
```

and I need a list of Int like:

```
[[6,5,3],[4,1,4,],[3,7,6]]
```

this is the source code:

```
import System.IO
import qualified Data.Text    as Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text

main = do
    ls <- fmap Text.lines (Text.readFile "file.txt")
```

Comment: This is easy to do: `map read` will produce for instance `[[6,5,4]]` from `["[6,5,4]"]`, provided the typing is clear.

Comment: `read "[3,7,6]" :: [Int]` will give `[3,7,6]`.

Comment: Note that to use `read` you will need to use `Text.unpack` first, or use the `String` functions to read the file instead of the `Text` ones.

Comment: @Elmex80s does it work with char? like read "[A,B,C]" :: [Char]

Comment: `read "['A','B','C']" :: [Char]` will give `"ABC"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `read`:

```
l = ["[6,5,3]","[4,1,4]","[3,7,6]"]
[read x :: [Int] | x <- l]
=> [[6,5,3],[4,1,4],[3,7,6]]
```

If the line `["[6,5,3]","[4,1,4]","[3,7,6]"]` is a full string you can just read all of it:

`read line :: [[Int]]`